# trace java program execution

Tags: java, trace

I am having a hard time finding some program to trace the execution of a java program.

For a starter just something that would give me like all method calls and time spent doing each call would be nice.

Do you have any suggestion ? Thank you in advance

EDIT : i would like to get the whole call tree, or hierarchy, whatever it is exactly called, from startup, with time spent, and i couldn't get it with VisualVM. 
I found a screenshot of some tools that supposedly could do it but i haven't gone through with it and i would like something more simple to begin with :
[image]

That would be pretty close to what i have in mind : it gives a trace of some method call tree, the time spent in each method, even a representation of it.

What were the original problems i was trying to solve ? Here is almost the whole story : 
First, i am working on some tool that has to populate some knowledge base. I recently realized that it was pretty slow (some specific request, that is adding ~30 entities to the base would take more than 20 seconds), so i would like to know if the time is spent on my code, on the network (REST call to update that knowledge base), in the knowledge base itself, or in my code.
And if my code is slow, i want to know what exactly it is doing that is taking so much time.

Another reason is that i was reading "Effective Java 3rd edition", great book btw. In the item 6 "Avoid creating unnecessary objects"

There is this code snippet :

```
// Hideously slow! Can you spot the object creation?
private static long sum() {
  Long sum = 0L;
  for (long i = 0; i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++)
    sum += i;
  return sum;
}
```

compared to that one :

```
private static long sum() {
  long sum = 0L;
  for (long i = 0; i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++)
    sum += i;
  return sum;
}
```

I can see that he second version will take less time, i understand why, there are no Long object instanciated, etc. but i would like to see, with actual measures, how long exactly it is taking doing instanciations, see with measures the number of instances of Long, and other objects are being created, what percentage of memory Long objects are taking in that case etc.

And some other experiences at work, where we would blindly do some great deal of refactoring, some heated debates about whether some implementation X were "more efficient" than implementation Y, but actually we never have any data to back it up.

All in all, i realize i needed tool to get actual and solid data about what the code is doing, what is happening in the JVM, how much memory is being allocated, by what object, how much time is being spent doing what, etc.

That contains A LOT of specific questions, and my first one was this one :
"how can i trace the execution of even a simple program".

Thank you and sorry for not being super specific to begin with.

And the other post that was suggested didn't help THAT much, using VisualVM with the plugin Profile Startup, on the toy example from Effective Java, i can get something when i count up to Integer.MAX_VALUE,

[image]

but if i only count up to 1.000.000 for example it looks like VisualVM doesn't have time to get started (although i thought launching my program with the option -agentpath:/home/joseph/dev/visualvm_142/profiler/lib/deployed/jdk16/linux-amd64/libprofilerinterface.so=/home/joseph/dev/visualvm_142/profiler/lib,5140 would let VisualVM start but all i get is a blank screen with "Status : profiling inactive" but it's all the same as the execution where i was counting to Integer.MAX_VALUE, i just dont' get it) :

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with the debugger in IDEs like Eclipse or IntelliJ Idea?

Comment: @shriyog these debuggers only let you trace the logic flow and inspect variable values. They neither log anything nor measure the time taken by anything

Comment: yes, but i am not talking about a step by step execution, if that's what you had in mind. Otherwise i would be glad to hear about some feature i am not aware of

Comment: My favorite is JProfiler but its not free.

Comment: This sounds like one of those "AB problems", where someone asks about a specific way they have thought of to solve a problem, but haven't detailed what the problem is. Other than intellectual curiousity, I can't think of a good reason why you would want to do this. Why *DO* you want to do this, maybe we can help you with the real issue instead of this one. Or, if it's intellectual curiousity, then we can just tell you we don't know of such a tool. Tools that sample, yes, tools that trace, no.

Comment: Do you use the Oracle-JVM? this comes with interesting tooling: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html

Comment: Marvin I heard about it, i would prefer a free alternative. I guess i'm definitely not the first one with that "need" or request, there has to be a free solution, even possibly already already packaged with the jdk.

@arcy i edited my post to include the WHY of my request. There is indeed a bit of intellectual curiosity, but there is more to it that that. And even if so, i really would like to be able to trace the execution of a Java program, i am in the process of trying to master (at least parts of) java, and it's like my brain need that.

TimothyTruckle i will take a look thanks

Comment: @josephM'Bimbi-Bene I think the intellecutal curiousity can be satisfied with a debugger -- you don't need automated tracing to see what's being done in the example you give us (which is guaranteed to crash, by the way, overflowing the Long or long or whatever). As to how much time is spent, how much memory allocated, etc., I think those questions are *better* answered by a profiler or similar tool, which samples execution and summarizes for you instead of tracing each statement, or even each method call. "Step Into", "Step Over",and "Step out of" are your friends!

Comment: I'm going to offer a comment on the program snippet of your example. The part of it that I find useful is what I call its "pathological inefficiency"; there is no reason to have an object in that loop, so why have one? Java gave us primitives specifically so that it could operate on some things efficiently without the object overhead. I wouldn't call it "hideously slow" because I suspect a human watching the program execute might not be able to tell which one was running. It's curious that they give an example which cannot run to completion; it's going to overflow before it gets to the end.

Comment: thank you for the time you take replying to me.
But as far as intellectual curiosity, i exhausted the debugger.
The little example with the Long is ... just an explanation of what brought me to write this post, since i understood that was what you were asking. I actually understand what is going on in this program, for each loop turn it allocates a Long, which takes way more time and memory than a primitive, but the point of my post was that i would like hard DATA about what is going on inside of my program, inside of the JVM while it is being executed.

Comment: And in fact the program terminates, the Long created in the loop is immediately eligible for garbage collection as the turn loop turn starts (sorry i feel like it might not be the correct term but english is not my native language) and the Long no longer is referenced by anything, and i can actually see that in Visual VM and VisualGC as the heap fills up and the GC is triggered, all that repeatedly

Comment: And i would like data of the execution of some program, not for that toy example specifically (althoug i would probably experiment with it), but as a general tool.

You answered with profilers, about that and the toy example, i posted a screenshot that shows that i apparently can't get any data with visualVM if my program is too quick, for some reason.

But for more general cases, i understand that it's worth spending time mastering those tools, don't worry i plan to do that too, for it doesn't address this specific need of a tracer of some sort

Comment: Flight Recorder is free in JDK 11, but it uses sampling instead of tracing (and for a good reason). The overhead of instrumenting every method call would skew the results (and how the JVM optimize methods) so you would not get what you are looking for. Sampling on the other hand will show you the hottest methods. If you have a particular method you want to investigate, you could try  JMH microbenchmark framework.

Comment: @KireHaglin I guess it is nice to have those tools in ones toolbox. I gave a quick try to Flight Recorder through Java Mission Control, but i can't follow it live, apparently it generates some file that i can only investigate afterwards, which is a bit annoying. I would hope to be able to do both, follow live and investigate through a file of some sort, but it is what it is.

I don't fully understand how instrumenting every call would skew the results, i get some hunches, but not a solid understanding.

Comment: I mean, even without monitoring, i guess there has to be some event of some sort emitted in the JVM for each method call, an external tool could listen them and do some reporting and analysis, timestamp of the method call, return, CPU and memory usage at the beginning and end of that call, you could be very creative with what other metrics you would like to add. You could have a black/whitelist of classes and method to listen to.

As far as JMH, i discovered it a few days ago, definitely worth adding to my toolbox, i will certainly use it in future projects

Answer (score 0):

This little "Trace" tool developed by Oracle might help you:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/trace.html

It is based on Java Debug Interface (JDI).

I was really keen on using it, but I have spent 10 minutes looking for the Oracle examples to download, without being able to find them.

In the past I have used a lot BTrace https://github.com/btraceio/btrace  , I see that it's still being actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

The correct term is **profiling**. Because of the long list of long (Long?) comments I make it an answer.

Your commercial IntelliJ IDEA, and the NetBeans IDE have a profiler, where you can start a profile, take snapshots to compare, find critical paths, memory usage, bottlenecks, time durations. You might want to compare them, though IntelliJ is likely to be better.

Then there are **code style checkers** like SonarLint, that just may find things like calculating with wrapped types.